# How to load the plugin only when logged in?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

as a matter of performance for the entire system, how to do it correctly, if there is a way, to make the code of my plugin read or interpreted only when the user will login, as it is only and exclusively to work when the user is logged in.

In this way, I decrease the load on the site, not having to run or read everything every request on the site.

I was thinking of doing something similar to that, but I still haven't found a more viable way

```
$pluginPath = 'myPlugin/myPlugin.php';
if (is_plugin_active($pluginPath) && stripos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'wp-admin') == true) {
...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  How is your plugin triggered?  Are you hooked to a certain WP action?  Without knowing what your plugin does, or where it fires, answering that question will be very open ended.  Recommend adding more detail to your question and you are more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Do you mean your plug-in only has functions used in the admin, or does it affect the front of the site for logged in users?

Comment: I simply want it to take effect, only when logged in, as there is nothing in this plugin, which should work if you are not logged in.

Comment: in my logical thinking, if wordpress doesn’t read and load unnecessary files, it could increase performance considerably, and safely, too

Comment: file loading on its own doesn't have much of an impact on performance in WordPress, any gains you get will be very difficult to measure.

Answer (score 1):

When I create custom plugins I tend to add a single init function, which includes other plugin files, attached functions from these files to actions and hooks, etc. This way I have centralized place where the plugin is bootstrapped. This init function is then hooked to the `plugins_loaded` action in case I need to do some dependecy checking - i.e. some other plugin needs to be installed and active too.

```
// your-main-plugin-file.php
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_init');
function my_plugin_init() {
    // check dependencies
    // include files
    // hook plugin function to actions and filters
    // etc...
}
```

But the `plugins_loaded` action fires too early, if you also need to check for a logged in user. In that case a good action to hook your main init function to would be `init` as the user is authenticated by the time it is fired.

```
add_action('init', 'my_plugin_init_logged_in_users');
function my_plugin_init_logged_in_users() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        my_plugin_init();
    }
}
```

You can find more information about the different WP actions, their order and what data is available to them when they fire, in the [Action reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Answer (score 0):

is_user_logged_in() Would do it. So let's assume you're loading scripts only when the user is logged in, you can write:

```
function load_user_scripts(){

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       wp_enqueue_script( , , string[] $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false );

}}
```

And call it in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_user_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your interested in optimization, you can try one of the many optimization plugins that minify and defer scripts. I particularly like "Asset Cleanup" because you can disable/remove unnecessary plugin scripts on specific pages (i.e. CF7 on the home page, or any Woocommerce  plugin on non Woocommerce pages)